# How to load transparent materials using assimp?

Tags: c++, assimp

I've got a simple scene with a transparent wall and 2 cubes.

[image]

The the base color of the transparent wall in Blender is set to: `RGBA = {0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3}`

I've exported the scene to the `gltf` format and loaded it using assimp.

My material extraction code looks like this (it may be kinda messy, because I've been playing around with it to find the solution):

```cpp
void ExtractMaterial(const aiScene* scene)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> customProperties;
    if (scene->HasMaterials()) {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < scene->mNumMaterials; i++) {
            auto aiMaterial = scene->mMaterials[i];
            auto aiMaterialName = aiMaterial->GetName();

            aiColor4D aiColor;
            if (aiMaterial->Get(AI_MATKEY_COLOR_DIFFUSE, aiColor) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            float opacity = 1.0f;
            if (aiMaterial->Get(AI_MATKEY_OPACITY, opacity) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            float transFac = 1.0f;
            if (aiMaterial->Get(AI_MATKEY_TRANSPARENCYFACTOR, transFac) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            float transCol = 1.0f;
            if (aiMaterial->Get(AI_MATKEY_COLOR_TRANSPARENT, transCol) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            for (int p = 0; p < aiMaterial->mNumProperties; p++) {
                aiMaterialProperty* pt = aiMaterial->mProperties[p];
                switch (pt->mType) {
                    case aiPTI_String: {
                        const char* data = pt->mData;
                        customProperties[pt->mKey.C_Str()] = data;
                    }
                    break;
                    case aiPTI_Float: {
                        std::stringstream ss;
                        ss << *(float*)pt->mData;
                        customProperties[pt->mKey.C_Str()] = ss.str();

                        if (strcmp(pt->mKey.C_Str(), "$mat.opacity") == 0) {
                            float num = *(float*)pt->mData;
                            if (num != 1.0) {
                                std::cout << std::endl;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (strcmp(pt->mKey.C_Str(), "$mat.gltf.alphaMode") == 0) {
                            float mode = *(float*)pt->mData;

                            std::cout << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set breakpoints in places where `std::cout << std::endl;` is written. `std::cout << std::endl;` is to enforce the debugger to execute the code in these places.

`aiColor4D aiColor;` of the wall is the same as in Blender except for the `alpha` which is `1.0f` (should be `0.3f`).

The rest variables `opacity`, `transFac`, `transCol` and the `customProperties` map are just for me to check out which one is the actual alpha value. None of them is.

How do I get the alpha value of the wall?

The material *should* be exported fine because the default Windows 10 3D mesh explorer works fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if AI_MATKEY_OPACITY is set. But it could be the case that we have an issue here. I will check it and create a new bug report for this. Thanks a lot for the hint.